# Modular math reducing to remainder modulo

Tags: math, modulo

I need some help with modulo. I saw this example in my book and don't understand how my prof got it. Can someone explain to me how this works?

2^345 = (2^5)^69 = 32^69 = 1^69 = 1 (mod 31)

The = signs are congruence signs.

Comment: Note that 32 mod 31 = 1

Comment: This is due to a very simple congruence: (a*b) (mod c) = ((a mod c) * (b mod c)) (mod c).

Answer (score 2):

Only the third sign needs be congruence, actually: 2^345 = (2^5)^69 (because n^(a*b) == (n^a)^b); 2^5 is certainly 32; and 1^n = 1 for all n.

So, why is 32^69 ~= 1^69 (using ~= as "congruent to")?

Simple.

```
32 ~= 1 mod (31) =>
32 = (n*31)+1    =>
32^p = ((n*31)+1)^p
     = (n*31)^p + a*1*(n*31)^(p-1) + b*(1^2)*(n*31)^(p-1) + ... + 1^p for some a,b...
     = (n*31)*z + 1 for some z
    ~= 1 (mod 31)
```

In general, therefore, if `a ~= b (mod p)` then `a^n ~= b^n (mod p)`